# Problem with org-todo done function

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am trying to log all my todos in a `archive.org` file, by means of the following function:

```
 (defun mark-done-and-archive ()
    (interactive)
    (org-todo 'done)
    (org-archive-subtree))
  (define-key global-map "\C-c\C-x\C-s" 'mark-done-and-archive)
```

The part to move the todos to the archive works,  but `(org-todo 'done)` isn't working and in the archive the todo appears as TODO and not  as DONE. If I try to eval `(org-todo 'done)` in org-buffer with `M-: (org-todo 'done)`, it works so I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine, the problem is the key binding. You are binding this key sequence in the global map. When you are in an org buffer, that binding will instead be resolved against `org-mode-map`, so you'll get the default archive command.

You can verify this: in your org buffer, try `C-h k C-c C-x C-s` and you'll see it is bound to `org-archive-subtree`.

There are various ways to bind the key for org mode. For example:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda () (local-set-key "\C-c\C-x\C-s" 'mark-done-and-archive)))
```